# Flutter: Padding on a scaled Image

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter, but I thought I was on the right track here.

I've tried using the `padding` attribute on a Container, as well as wrapping the element (or parent elements) inside of a `new Padding()`. The below is only a portion of the layout, but the offending part.

```
new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Image.network(_choiceOne,
                height: 200.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
          )
        )
      ],
    )
```

I've also tried using a `Decoration` on parent elements to produce the desired "padding", but I still end up with the renderer flipping out. I think it has something to do with the scaling of the random image's I'm retrieving, but am not sure.

The start of the error is: `A horizontal RenderFlex overflowed by 11 pixels.`

With the error tree being listed as `Row ← Column ← Container ← Chooser ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Center ← MediaQuery ←`

[image: The offending issue]

Comment: they're good boys

Answer (score 2):

Try using margin instead of padding.

Comment: The image is as a child. Not a decoration. So this won't change anything.

Comment: A margin produces the same overflow issue

Answer (score 1):

you can also do

```
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
    height: 200.0
  ),
  child: Image.network(_choiceOne),
)
```

Comment: A code-only answer is a low-quality answer. Add some explanation as to why you think this code-snippet would work.

Comment: really? can you reference the meta post that says that?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307231/5670752. I'm not a fan of recommending deletion on code-only answers.. but I believe that a little explanation is always more helpful than none.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving height in child widget `Image.network`, give `minHeight`, `maxheight`, `minWidth`, and `maxWidth` in parent widget and set `fit: BoxFit.fitWidth` in child widget.